# what is a good way to load test and report on a web application?

Tags: testing, web, load-testing

I have a web application and I need to report on how much load it can handle; things like maximum transactions per second, max number of simultaneous users, and so on.

How should I go about testing this?  What are good/easy tools (free or not) to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three things to begin with:

- http://blitz.io/ (no installation required)
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html
- http://code.google.com/p/httperf/

Answer (score 0):

That is a very generalized question (how to load test a web app?), so I'll give an equally general answer:

1. Determine the goals of your testing - what questions are you trying to answer?
2. Create a model of the expected load on your system (how many concurrent users? what are they doing? how fast are they doing it?)
3. Select and develop the scenarios to be tested
4. Find out how performance will be measured and what performance is considered unacceptable
5. Choose a performance testing tool that will support your efforts as efficiently as possible in both time and money (insert shameless plug for [Web Performance Load Tester](http://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/load-tester.html))
6. Run a test
7. Analyze the results in respect to the performance goals from #3 and report the results to the project stakeholders
8. Refine 1-5 as needed and repeat 6 & 7

Each of those steps has a good bit of complexity to them -- too much to delve into here.  Our blog has a lot of [good load testing tips](http://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/blog/category/load-testing/) that might help you get started.